# Spinner selected value isn't being uploaded to firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm making a shopping app and I want to upload the selected value of the spinner to my database. The value is being uploaded to the database but it's not the right value, that is being uploaded. Here's my code.

```
mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);


    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names));
    myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mySpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    selectedValue = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

...

```
private void addingToCartList()
{
    String saveCurrentTime, saveCurrentDate;

    Calendar calForDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
    saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(calForDate.getTime());
    SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a");
    saveCurrentTime = currentTime.format(calForDate.getTime());

    final DatabaseReference cartListRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cart List");

    final HashMap<String, Object> cartMap = new HashMap<>();
    cartMap.put("pid", productID);
    cartMap.put("pname", productName.getText().toString());
    cartMap.put("price", productPrice.getText().toString());
    cartMap.put("date", saveCurrentDate);
    cartMap.put("time", saveCurrentTime);
    cartMap.put("quantity", selectedValue);
    cartMap.put("discount", "");
    cartListRef.child("User View").child(Prevelant.currentOnlineUser.getUsername())
            .child("Products").child(productID)
            .updateChildren(cartMap)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                {
                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        cartListRef.child("Admin View").child(Prevelant.currentOnlineUser.getUsername())
                                .child("Products").child(productID)
                                .updateChildren(cartMap)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                                    {
                                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                                        {
                                            Toast.makeText(ProductDetails2Activity.this, "Added to Cart List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            Intent intent = new Intent (ProductDetails2Activity.this, CartActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

[image: String array]

And everytime the value that is being uploaded to the database is 250

[image: database]

I want to solve that...

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should get the selected item after the user has clicked submit but you are getting the value even before he has changed it so by default it is taking the first one

```
private void addingToCartList()
{
String saveCurrentTime, saveCurrentDate;

Calendar calForDate = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(calForDate.getTime());
SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a");
saveCurrentTime = currentTime.format(calForDate.getTime());

//putting spinner here
selectedValue = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

final DatabaseReference cartListRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cart List");

final HashMap<String, Object> cartMap = new HashMap<>();
cartMap.put("pid", productID);
cartMap.put("pname", productName.getText().toString());
cartMap.put("price", productPrice.getText().toString());
cartMap.put("date", saveCurrentDate);
cartMap.put("time", saveCurrentTime);
cartMap.put("quantity", selectedValue);
cartMap.put("discount", "");
cartListRef.child("User View").child(Prevelant.currentOnlineUser.getUsername())
        .child("Products").child(productID)
        .updateChildren(cartMap)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
            {
                if(task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    cartListRef.child("Admin View").child(Prevelant.currentOnlineUser.getUsername())
                            .child("Products").child(productID)
                            .updateChildren(cartMap)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                                {
                                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                                    {
                                        Toast.makeText(ProductDetails2Activity.this, "Added to Cart List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        Intent intent = new Intent (ProductDetails2Activity.this, CartActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        });
}
```

I Hope This works
Lemme know if it works